# Grouping nodes by common CCK values in views

Tags: views, 6

I can't think of a better title than that, but hopefully it makes sense once I describe it.

I have a node type with 3 CCK fields, we'll call them A,B,C and 1,2,3 and X,Y,Z.

Some nodes will be A,1,X and others will be B,3,Z and etc.

I want to create a view which will pull all of my nodes and list each unique option set as a row so all rows that are A,1,X are in a row with the # of results, and all B,3,Z's are in a row with the # of results.

Is what I want to do possible? If so - how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible: On your view you have filters, you can filter results by A, then another view with all the results of B; then, if you want these both in a single page I'd suggest a Panels page.